# The functional equation $x(x+1)+C(x)=(x+1)(x+2)+C(x+1)=(x+2)(x+3)+C(x+2)=...$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Consider the functional equation
$$x(x+1)+C(x)=(x+1)(x+2)+C(x+1)=(x+2)(x+3)+C(x+2)=...$$
The equality continues to infinity.

Is there $C(x)$ that satisfies all the equality?
If there is, what is it?

---

I missed the simple solution $C(x)=c-x(x+1)$. My main question though is whether there are other solutions.

Comment: Let $c$ be any constant. Then $C(t)=c-t(t+1)$ does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We describe the general solution. For $0\le t\lt 1$, let $g(t)$ be *arbitrary*. For any real number $x$, let $f(x)=g(\{x\})$, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. Let $C(x)=f(x)-x(x+1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert mathematician and cannot entirely understand what you're saying. what is g(x) supposed to represent?

Comment: I am sorry also, there was a typo at the end, it is supposed to be $f(x)-x(x+1)$. The point is that the equations you give force a relationship between $C(x)$ and $C(x+n)$ when $n$ is an integer. In particular, there need be no relationship whatsoever between $C(5.6)$ and $C(99.3)$. That's where the aribitrary function $g(t)$ comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

$$C(x)=-x(x+1)$$

Note that this makes $0$ every term of the "infinite" equation.

Note also that this solution is far from being unique.

Comment: Very clever, I totally missed that. But is there any other equation?